# JavaScript first time uploading

Tags: javascript

It's my first time using javascript library. I wanted to use Microsoft Office Clippy on my page from https://www.smore.com/clippy-js

My problem is the .load function, it displays in a orange colour so something is wrong

```
<script src="jquery.1.7.min.js">  </script>

<!-- Clippy.js -->
<script src="clippy.min.js"></script>

<!-- Init script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
clippy.load('Merlin', function(agent) {
    // Do anything with the loaded agent
    agent.show();
});
</script>
```

I don't know how to connect it to the sources library which is here https://github.com/smore-inc/clippy.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the file that is [here](https://github.com/smore-inc/clippy.js/blob/master/build/clippy.min.js) (inside the build folder of the github that you linked) and put in your project folder, in the same folder of the file that you are calling him, or in another folder but you have to edit he src to match the file.

Comment: note that you also need to download and put in your project the css that is in the build folder of that github so everything working fine

Comment: There is no project folder because I'm doing it as a subpage of a basic platform where I can just edit html. Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Well, if you cant download and incorporate anything to the pages, you can copy and paste the code and put it inside of a <script> tag (<script>...code...</script>)